# XSLT looping through nodes to get a desired hierarchy

Tags: loops, xslt

I have a xml. I want to get the value of `<child1>` depending on the value of `<key>BA</key>`.My XSLT is retrieving all the values of `<child1>` as shown. I would like get the values of `<child1>` depending on `<key>BA</key>` as I have shown in Desired XML Output.

XML data:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Parent>
    <parent1 id="parent1_313_1">
        <child1>Child_value1</child1>
        <records>
            <record id="parent1_313_1_r1">
                <data>
                    <entry>
                        <key>AA</key>
                        <value>AA1</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>BA</key>
                        <value>BA1</value>
                    </entry>
                </data>
            </record>
            <record id="parent1_313_1_r2">
                <data>
                    <entry>
                        <key>AA</key>
                        <value>AA1</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>BA</key>
                        <value>BA1</value>
                    </entry>
                </data>
            </record>
     </records>  
</parent1>
 <parent1 id="parent2_313_1">
        <child1>Child_blank</child1>
        <records>
            <record id="parent2_313_1_r1">
                <data>
                    <entry>
                        <key>AA</key>
                        <value>AA1</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>BA</key>
                        <value></value>
                    </entry>
                </data>
            </record>
            <record id="parent2_313_1_r2">
                <data>
                    <entry>
                        <key>AA</key>
                        <value>AA1</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>BA</key>
                        <value></value>
                    </entry>
                </data>
            </record>
     </records>  
</parent1>
<parent1 id="parent3_313_1">
        <child1>Child_value3</child1>
        <records>
            <record id="parent3_313_1_r1">
                <data>
                    <entry>
                        <key>AA</key>
                        <value>AA1</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>BA</key>
                        <value>BA3</value>
                    </entry>
                </data>
            </record>
            <record id="parent3_313_1_r2">
                <data>
                    <entry>
                        <key>AA</key>
                        <value>AA1</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>BA</key>
                        <value>BA3</value>
                    </entry>
                </data>
            </record>
     </records>  
</parent1>
<parent1 id="parent4_313_1">
        <child1>Child_value4</child1>
        <records>
            <record id="parent4_313_1_r1">
                <data>
                    <entry>
                        <key>AA</key>
                        <value>AA1</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>BA</key>
                        <value>BA3</value>
                    </entry>
                </data>
            </record>
            <record id="parent4_313_1_r2">
                <data>
                    <entry>
                        <key>AA</key>
                        <value>AA1</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>BA</key>
                        <value>BA3</value>
                    </entry>
                </data>
            </record>
     </records>  
</parent1>
</Parent>
```

My XSLt code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
               xmlns:xyz="http://www.tridan.it/xyz"  
               version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="APOS" select='"&apos;"'/>

    <xsl:function name="xyz:formatId">
        <xsl:param name="unformattedId"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate($unformattedId, concat(' &amp;/()][*,’|\',$APOS), '_')"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:variable name="ccName2" select="Parent/parent1/child1"/>
            <cccs>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="Parent/parent1/records/record/data/entry[key='BA']" group-by="value">
                        <xsl:variable name="ccName1" select="current-group()[1]/value"/>
                        <ccc>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$ccName1=''">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="xyz:formatId('BA_unknown')"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <name><xsl:value-of select="'Default'"/></name>
                                </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="xyz:formatId(concat('BA','_',$ccName1))"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <name><xsl:value-of select="$ccName1"/></name>
                                    
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <cccs>
                            
                                <xsl:for-each-group select="distinct-values($ccName2)" group-by="$ccName2">
                                <ccc>
                                       
                                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                                <xsl:choose>
                                                
                                                    <xsl:when test="$ccName1=''">
                                                         
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="xyz:formatId(concat('BA_Unknown','_',current-grouping-key()))"/>
                                                    </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="$ccName1!=''">
                                                         <xsl:value-of select="xyz:formatId(concat('BA','_',$ccName1,'_',current-grouping-key()))"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                </xsl:choose>       
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <name>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                                        </name>
                                        
                                </ccc>
                            
                                </xsl:for-each-group>   
                            </cccs>
                        </ccc>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </cccs>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Output XML Actual:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cccs xmlns:xyz="http://www.tridan.it/xyz">
    <ccc id="BA_BA1">
        <name>BA1</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="BA_BA1_Child_value1">
                <name>Child_value1</name>
            </ccc>
            <ccc id="BA_BA1_Child_blank">
                <name>Child_blank</name>
            </ccc>
            <ccc id="BA_BA1_Child_value3">
                <name>Child_value3</name>
            </ccc>
            <ccc id="BA_BA1_Child_value4">
                <name>Child_value4</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccc>
    <ccc id="BA_unknown">
        <name>Default</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="BA_Unknown_Child_value1">
                <name>Child_value1</name>
            </ccc>
            <ccc id="BA_Unknown_Child_blank">
                <name>Child_blank</name>
            </ccc>
            <ccc id="BA_Unknown_Child_value3">
                <name>Child_value3</name>
            </ccc>
            <ccc id="BA_Unknown_Child_value4">
                <name>Child_value4</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccc>
    <ccc id="BA_BA3">
        <name>BA3</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="BA_BA3_Child_value1">
                <name>Child_value1</name>
            </ccc>
            <ccc id="BA_BA3_Child_blank">
                <name>Child_blank</name>
            </ccc>
            <ccc id="BA_BA3_Child_value3">
                <name>Child_value3</name>
            </ccc>
            <ccc id="BA_BA3_Child_value4">
                <name>Child_value4</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccc>
</cccs>
```

Output XML Desired :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cccs xmlns:xyz="http://www.tridan.it/xyz">
    <ccc id="BA_BA1">
        <name>BA1</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="BA_BA1_Child_value1">
                <name>Child_value1</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccc>
    <ccc id="BA_unknown">
        <name>Default</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="BA_Unknown_Child_blank">
                <name>Child_blank</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccc>
    <ccc id="BA_BA3">
        <name>BA3</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="BA_BA3_Child_value3">
                <name>Child_value3</name>
            </ccc>
            <ccc id="BA_BA3_Child_value4">
                <name>Child_value4</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccc>
</cccs>
```

I think my inner loop is not fetching the correct data. I am new to XSLT. Please share where I am missing the information.

Comment: Please explain the required logic in words.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to group only once:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="Parent">
      <cccs>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="parent1/child1" group-by="..//entry[key = 'BA']/value">
              <ccc id="BA_{if (current-grouping-key()) then current-grouping-key() else 'unknown'}">
                <name>{if (current-grouping-key()) then current-grouping-key() else 'default'}</name>
                <cccs>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </cccs>
              </ccc>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </cccs>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="child1">
    <ccc id="BA_{if (current-grouping-key()) then current-grouping-key() else 'unknown'}_{.}">
      <name>{.}</name>
    </ccc>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehW12gj

Comment: Thanks Martin, that was really helpful. I was moving with a different approach.
The only thing now I need is distinct values from a group. How can I get that?

Comment: Is there any value missing if you use my suggestion above? What kind of distinct value do you need?